# How to insert an element into a custom array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I have an assignment and I'm quite confused about the concept of lists and generics. I don't understand why the template for our coding assignment includes what appears to be an array of generics "private Item[] items;" if generics don't work well with arrays. I need to make all this methods that where defined on the list interface to handle ArrList.

```
public class ArrList<T> implements ListInterface<T>{

  private int maxSize=10; 
  private myObj<T>[] objects; 
  private int count;  

  ArrList(){
  objects = new myObj<T>[maxSize];//I did this
  count = 0;
}
```

The method I'm having a hard time with is inserting an element into an array with less than maxSize nonempty elements and shifting those elements. Like:
1 2 3 4 5 _ _ _ _ _  inserting 8 at position 2 would yield:
1 2 8 3 4 5 _ _ _ _ I know how to do this if I was allowed to make an array  of the items with the same elements before the position as the original objects array, but with the differently shifted rest of the array and then copy to the objects array,(must be void method). But I don't know how to do this with only altering the original array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A basic for-loop can handle this:

```
for (int i = count; i > insert; i--)
    objects[i] = objects[i - 1];

objects[insert] = newValue;
```

This starts at the end of the array, and pulls items to the right, one at a time, until it gets to the index that you want to insert into. After doing this, you can write your value to the array, without losing any other entries.

About the generics - you can't create an array of generic types in Java, it just doesn't work out. One alternative is to store everything in an array of type `Object[]`, and cast return values to the appropriate type.